# How to run a C++ executable from hadoop python wrapper

Tags: python, c++, hadoop

I am new in hadoop streaming library using python. So the question may look stupid but I got stuck here badly. Any help is appreciated.

I am trying to run a C++ executable (which takes a local filename as command line argument and write a file in local file system) from a python code which serves as mapper in hadoop. The C++ code is working fine in local file system. Also when I am calling it from python it is working fine in local file system. But, Whenever, I am trying to call the python as hadoop, mapper it is not working.

What is the reason for that? Any ideas?

Comment: What is "not working"?  Do you have something more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can verify that your Python code is able to execute the binary locally, you should make sure to deploy the C++ binary also to the worker machines to make it available for Mappers. [You can use the `-file` command line argument for this.](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.2/streaming.html#Packaging+Files+With+Job+Submissions)